# Import users via console application asp.net Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

I have a list of new users that I need to import into my web application that is using ASP.NET Identity 2.

The UserManager and such is the default code that comes with the project.  I've implemented nothing custom.

I've fought it for a while and just can't find the magic bullet.

I am using a console application reading from an excel file. I create a random password and try, but my attempts have had various degrees of failure.

Sorry for lack of code samples but I don't feel I have anything good to add to the question.

Comment: so what exactly is the question?

Comment: How to do it.  I can't get correct instances of usermanager and such going.  I'm a little surprised this question isn't asked out on the webs.  Seems like it would be a common step.

Comment: do you have to do it in console app? I think it'll be much easier to create a MVC action that takes a spreadsheet, parses it and uses `ApplicationUserManager` to create users. I don't see a need for stand-alone console app - it will just make things extra complex. As for common step - it is not so common. I've done export of users via SQL scripts.

Comment: Well, ultimately processing it via a web interface is not what the web is designed for.  HOWEVER, I did end up doing it via a action.

The problem with the sql route is hashing the passwords.  These are new accounts.

Comment: No, not the best, but if it is one off, then it'll do. If it is a repetitive task, leave it as a web-action, so your clients can do that themselves.